# ERROR: Permission to gitTest.git denied to deploy key fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

I created a repository named "gitTest", and cloned to my local. When I want to push it to the remote, I got the following log:

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
dd@dd:~/Desktop/Repositories/gitTest$ git push
ERROR: Permission to xinfengwu/gitTest.git denied to deploy key
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
dd@dd:~/Desktop/Repositories/gitTest$
```

I use ssh-key to access github.

```
dd@dd:~/Desktop/Repositories/gitTest$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi xinfengwu/xinfengwu.github.io! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```